# Nginx:504 Gateway Timeout

Tags: node.js, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am using Nginx as my https server to serve my http content from my node server.

I am also hosting my server on google cloud.

I have been keep getting a 504 Gateway Timeout Error; So I wonder if it is because I didnt set my upstream server (node server) 8080 port open. Then it works. Not so sure if it is the correct way to do it

[image]

But then I kept looking other docs or tutorial online. I never see people configure in such way to connect to node server. They mainly only left the port 80 opened. So I wondered if my config in server block causing the 504 gateway problem

[image]

[image]

----------second update

this is my setting, and the default_server is written by default
[image]

but i always see doc have included a variable - server_name ; Actually I dont quite understand this varibale. May I know should I consider it or not for later use, although it works  now

[image]

Aside, I got an
Server Error from my app.

FetchError: request to https://34.96.213.54:443/search/guest2 failed, reason: self-signed certificate

[image]

Why is that it works on chrome,although I get that api directly and postman successfully.

third updated------
[image]

Comment: using multiple servers in upstream is load balancing, you still just use single server backend in proxy_pass for simpler and smaller service, check more at https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/http-load-balancer/ and https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/

Comment: Thanks for comment, So my node js is not called a upstream server? But, whether opening my node server port for proxy server to connect to it is correct or not? I am just confused if this way is correct or not

Comment: "my node js is not called a upstream server" => it likes a upstream with just one server inside, two ways are both correct depend on your size of your service

Comment: Thanks for respone, But, how could I allow my ngxin proxy to my node server without exilically opening my 8080 port? Coz I just want only one entry point exposing outside

Comment: yes, you don't need to open 8080 to outside

Comment: yes, if I dont need to open 8080 outside... so if it is because of my config setting casuing the problem ? coz i actually have referenced the doc online, including the one you mentioned, to do my proxy pass setting. That's my original intention to ask the question

Comment: Did you proxy pass to http://localhost:8080 if nginx and node on same server?

Comment: yes. I wrote proxy pass " HTTP://34.123.34.132:8080 "  , instead of writing localhost. But they are in the same server. Did it matter?

Comment: since port 8080 is not public, you need to use a private address, because of same server, you need to use "localhost" instead of a public address

Comment: it works ! thanks a lot... btw , i also update the question to see if you can answer.... then i may can raise you as accepted?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242259/discussion-between-buithienquyet-and-hose).

Comment: sure, can you ping me? I havent had chat feature enabled yet

Answer (score 0):

About self-signed certificate: You need to buy one or using a free service like https://letsencrypt.org .Beside that your questions are so basic so you have to research more on nginx docs (http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html)

Comment: Thanks for the link, btw if it possible that I keep using my self-signed certificate without downloading a new one and get a free CA to acknowledge it? I just want to test it in a quick way. 

As for the server name, Now i understood now.

Comment: for " I just want to test it in a quick way ", it is fine!

Comment: but it keep saying failed, reason: self-signed certificate ... Sorry if this is too long already. I mean it is possible to send out for user to test

Comment: it depend on you, users will see warning messages from browsers and need to ignore that to continue

Comment: I understand what you said, but this time,  the user couldnt even see the warning messages. As this message is thrown by the app. picture attached

Comment: I don't know about detail of your app architech, You may try creating certificate for yourself https://www.google.com/search?q=generate+self+signed+certificate+for+nginx or more better a official certificate . Remember to research and try many times before asking questions :D

Comment: Thanks, but your reference only told me about self generated SSL, but I have created self generated ssl at the very beginning already.  But my struggle is the server error, my node couldnt fetch https, although i have self-generated ssl ; In chrome, it can route to https indeed.   But I guess it is so long already, I dont want to bother you anymore. So thanks a lot too! I will update this when I proceed anything!